# Data not sent to App Insights from ILogger in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

I have enabled the app insights logging in the application. From other places like controller, other classes I am able to use logger and the data is sent to application insights but in startup I tried to send the data to AI but its not pushing the data to AI. I am not getting any error, Instance is created but the data is not pushed to AI. Here is my startup

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public Startup(ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddLogging(log =>
        {
            log.AddApplicationInsights();
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        _logger.LogError("something");
    }
}
```

*appsettings.json*

```
"Logging": {
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "logLevel": { "default": "Information" }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reference [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> Only the following service types can be injected into the Startup constructor when using the Generic Host (IHostBuilder):
>
> - IWebHostEnvironment
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IConfiguration
>
> ...
>   Most services are not available until the `Configure` method is called.

As you are actually registering the logger within the `Startup` itself, it wont be ready by the time the class is instantiated.

Consider moving the logger registration out so that it is there by the time `Startup` is initialized.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); 
            });
}
```

In `Startup`, the desired logging behavior should now be available

```
public class Startup {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Startup(ILogger<Startup> logger) {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        _logger.LogError("something");
    }
}
```